Overlay in Angular CDK Overlay doesn't stay on top of other components
(https://i.sstatic.net/121lp.png)
**
I'm trying to use Angular CDK Overlay to create an overlay that should appear on top of my page content. However, despite setting position: absolute; and z-index: 9999;, the overlay is not staying on top and gets hidden behind other elements on the page.
**
Here's my HTML code
<div cdkOverlayOrigin #overlayPosition="cdkOverlayOrigin">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput #inputField (input)="filterOptions(inputField.value)" placeholder="Search..." (click)="detailsOpen=true">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay
             [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="overlayPosition"
             [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="detailsOpen"
             (overlayOutsideClick)="detailsOpen=false"
             style="position: absolute; top: calc(100% + 5px); width: 100%;">
    <div class="overlay-container mat-elevation-z2" style="position: relative; z-index: 9999;">
        <mat-list *ngIf="filteredOptions.length > 0">
            <mat-list-item *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" (click)="selectOption(option)">
                {{ option }}
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<div>
    <input type="text">
    <img src="favicon.ico">
</div>


I have tried setting the z-index to a high value, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I ensure that the overlay stays on top of the page content?
